# Django Google social-auth ModuleNotFoundError at /oauth/login/google-oauth2/

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

I am currently trying to setup social login with social-auth in django for a web app. Whenever I click the button on the webpage that links to a google login, I get this error on the django webpage:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError at /oauth/login/google-oauth2/

No module named 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2django'; 'social_core.backends.google' is not a package

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/login/google-oauth2/
Django Version:     3.0.5
Exception Type:     ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:    

No module named 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2django'; 'social_core.backends.google' is not a package

Exception Location:     C:\Users\isaac\OneDrive\Desktop\DeliverMeProj\venv\lib\site-packages\social_core\utils.py in import_module, line 56
Python Executable:  C:\Users\isaac\OneDrive\Desktop\DeliverMeProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\isaac\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DeliverMeProj',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\isaac\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DeliverMeProj\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\isaac\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DeliverMeProj\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\isaac\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 26 Apr 2020 04:12:34 +0000
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Have you installed `social-auth-app-django`?

Comment: Yes, I have that installed already.

Answer (score 3):

I actually figured this out. I was missing a comma in my AUTHENTICATIONBACKEND section.

So the problem looked like:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
```

)

And the solution is:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ***python-social-auth*** module

Please try this *pip install python-social-auth*

Please refer [here](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/) for more details.

Also make sure your settings.py files is having all the dependecies defined

You can try this  new library [social_core](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core?fireglass_rsn=true) as well.

Comment: That did not seem to work, I am still getting the same error. Although, when I ran "pip install python-social-auth", I recevied this error in the log: ERROR: python-social-auth 0.2.1 has requirement requests-oauthlib<0.3.2,>=0.3.0, but you'll have requests-oauthl
ib 1.3.0 which is incompatible.